# Paired t-test or comparison of difference?

Tags: ancova, paired-data, confounding

I want to compare anxiety levels of participants before and after an intervention in two groups. Firstly, I intended to use paired t-test, but I realized that there was a confounder that might effect the results.

So, I calculated the difference in anxiety levels before and after. Is it correct using ANCOVA to compare the  value of difference between groups when adjusting the confounders?

Comment: What would be your model equation?

Comment: The description needs some clarifications. For example, how many subjects in each group? Is the confounder measured at the subject level with one value before invention and one value after? What effects are your analytical focus or research interest?